# Celery: Number of workers per queue programmatically

Tags: python, task, celery

I'm creating queues dynamically `(CREATE_IF_MISSING=true)` and assign single worker once queue created. But this information isn't stored anywhere. So sometimes I want to query Celery for the following info:

1. if queue with given name already exists how many workers may consume
2. tasks from this queue(concurrency limit per queue)

Do you know any way to fetch this information from Celery ?

Cheers!

Comment: What did yo try? Did you search inside of Celery doc?

Comment: Of course, I read the docs, but no lock, probably I missed something. The only thing I've found is app.control.inspect().active_queues(). which shows only queues with running tasks. It is not exactly what I need.

Comment: decided to parse

rabbitmqctl -q list_queues name consumers